# Starting another script from button press on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so I am trying to create a button on tkinter that runs another script. I'm not sure whether this is the most optimal way rather than just adding whatever I have onto the script I want to run but I want to see if this is possible for future references. This is what I have on my script so far. Any ideas on how to approach this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
import uploadtest as ut

class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
#input fields for username and passwords
        Label(master, text="Scripts").grid(row=1, column=1),

#Buttons
        self.utz = ut

        self.b1 = Button(master, text = "Script1", bg="grey", command=self.utz)
        self.b1.grid(row=7, column=1, ipadx=75)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
d = Initial(root)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I can just add this class to the other script and use the button command and it would be easier, but I was just curious if this method was possible since I am going to be adding multiple scripts to this and I would like to have my scripts separated. It seems like when I try to import uploadtest.py on this script, it just runs that script instead of this one.

Comment: Make sure that you have the script in `uploadtest.py` within a function, else it will run the script as that's what happens when you import any module, and call that function from this script when needed to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use it again for future references you can modify your `uploadtest.py` to be a function

```
def ut():
    print("your")
    print("script")
    print("here")
```

then to use it in the script do `from uploadtest import *` and call it like a normal function that's in your script

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
from uploadtest import *
class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
#input fields for username and passwords
        Label(master, text="Scripts").grid(row=1, column=1),

#Buttons
        self.utz = ut

        self.b1 = Button(master, text = "Script1", bg="grey", command=self.utz)
        self.b1.grid(row=7, column=1, ipadx=75)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
d = Initial(root)
```

please comment if this is not what your looking for

Comment: thanks for the advice. I made uploadtest into a function but when I try to run this script, it just runs the uploadtest script without ever showing the script above. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `self.utz = ut()` should be `self.utz = ut`.